error: constexpr pointer initializer is not null
I have this very simple program:
int main(void)
{
    static constexpr const char *const str = "hello";
}

which fails to compile with this error:
$ gcc -std=c2x str.c
str.c: In function 'main':
str.c:6:46: error: 'constexpr' pointer initializer is not null
    6 |     static constexpr const char *const str = "hello";
      |                                              ^~~~~~~

$ gcc -v
...
gcc version 13.1.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders)

Why is nullptr the only pointer type allowed to be constexpr?

@OldBoy constexpr is part of C23/C24. The above code is valid C++ though, and compiles with g++ just fine. C's constexpr isn't as powerful. :)

Yes, I just checked that. But I also found the reason for your problem at constexpr specifier (since C23) - "_There are some restrictions on the type of an object that can be declared with constexpr. Namely, the following constructs are not allowed to be constexpr:
Pointers (except that null pointers can be constexpr),
Variably modified types,
Atomic types,
volatile types,
restrict pointers._"

The C23 standard explicitly states that pointers declared as constexpr must be null-initialized, as per section section 6.7.1p5:

An object declared with storage-class specifier constexpr or any of
its members, even recursively, shall not have an atomic type, or a
variably modified type, or a type that is volatile or restrict
qualified. The declaration shall be a definition and shall have an
initializer141). The value of any constant expressions or of any
character in a string literal of the initializer shall be exactly
representable in the corresponding target type; no change of value
shall be applied142). If an object or subobject declared with
storage-class specifier constexpr has pointer, integer, or arithmetic
type, the implicit or explicit initializer value for it shall be a
null pointer constant143), an integer constant expression, or an
arithmetic constant expression, respectively.

The named constant or compound literal constant corresponding to
an object declared with storage-class specifier constexpr and pointer
type is a constant expression with a value null, and thus a null
pointer and an address constant. However, even if it has type void * it
is not a null pointer constant.


The reason that only null pointers can be used to initialize a constexp pointer is because the value of a constexp must be known at translation time, i.e. when the code is parsed.  This is explained in section 6.7.1p11:

An object declared with a storage-class specifier constexpr has its
value permanently fixed at translation-time; if not yet present, a
const-qualification is implicitly added to the object’s type. The
declared identifier is considered a constant expression of the
respective kind, see ??.

This means that address constants, such as the start address of a string literal, which aren't known until the code is actually compiled, can't be used for constexp pointers.
Arguably, address constants should be allowed to initialized constexp pointers.

It is not necessary to know the actual address value to get the constexpr behavior. C++ doesn't have this restriction and instead chooses to make the pointer->integer conversion impossible at compile-time. And C permits the address of static storage duration objects as address constant expressions already. So I think it isn't obvious why this was excluded by WG14.

From the proposition introducing constrexpr to the C language https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3018.htm :

pointer types:
allowing these to use non-trivial addresses would delay the deduction of the concrete value from translation to link-time. For most of the use cases, such a feature can already be coded by using a static and const qualified pointer object, we don’t need constexpr for that. Therefore we only allow pointer types if the initializer value is null.


Why is nullptr the only pointer type allowed to be constexpr?

So that in C the constexpr pointer values can be fully calculated at translation time, without any linking.
